# Correcting clock drift in VM guests

Tags: virtual-machine, clock, ntp

I have a Unix O/S running as a guest under a hypervisor on a Linux host. The guest OS clock is 2s adrift from the host after 24 hours. I'd like to keep clocks in sync to less than a second for ease of log-analysis etc.

I know that running NTP under VM is [problematic](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/KnownOsIssues#Section_9.2.2.) ([somewhat](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf)). There are guest VM tools for clock sync provided by the hypervisor vendor, but not for this guest O/S (so far as I can discover).

I plan to run `ntpdate hostservername` hourly in cron. Is this reasonable or have I missed a more obvious solution?

Host: CentOS 5.7
Hypervisor: VMware Server 2
Guest: SCO OpenServer 5.0.7

Answer (score 3):

I've been running the ntp service on a VMware Workstation 9.0 instance for a while and haven't had any issues.

I just stopped it now and did a sync of it and got and offset of -0.003862 sec. (The guest OS is Ubuntu 12.04.1 Server x86_64 and has VMware Tools)

Personally I think if anything is going to give you grief it'd be SCO's products.